# Encoding method in python not working

Tags: python

Got a problem with `encoding` process.

```
      def str2bin(message):
          binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message), 16))
          return binary[2:]
```

The error is :

> binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message), 16))
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I'm trying to type only ascii in a program.  What is causing the error?

Comment: It's not clear what your title has to do with your question. Did you mean "steganography" rather than "stenography"? (Even then, it's still not clear.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the string, either in your function or before you pass it to your function:

```
import binascii

def str2bin(message):
    binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message.encode("ascii")), 16))
    return binary[2:]

print(str2bin("X")) # 1011000
```

The reason is, that `hexlify` expects a data type that supports the buffer interface.

A [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) does, a `str` does not.

See also the note on the `binascii` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

> a2b_* functions accept Unicode strings containing only ASCII characters. Other functions only accept **bytes-like objects** (such as bytes, bytearray and other objects that support the buffer protocol).